# C# Windows Phone Server Connect

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have been searching the internet for an answer but I cannot seem to find one. My question is, how would I go about sending data from a C# program I made on my Windows Phone to a C# server I have running on my PC. I am not looking for any code examples, just a quick overview on how I will do this.

Comment: I go about sending data from a C# program I made on my Windows Phone to a C# server ??? clear your question

Comment: I want to connect to my C# server from my Windows Phone as a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 'server'?

Also what is the server meant to do? If it's just for webservices then you could just use a http request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx otherwise you could establish a TCP (lossless) or UDP (lossy) connection with the server if you want to send packets back and forth (e.g. a persistent connection is needed).

Comment: Thank you for reply. The server is meant to store 10 of the highest scores in my game. When somebody acheives a high score, the score integer will be sent and stored on the server. The server I made is a TCP server.

Comment: For storing scores then I think you should just develop a webservice.

RESTful services are best and can be as trivial and as complicated as you like. e.g. http://myserver.com/postScore.php - in the http post body you could have JSON, XML, binary, whatever. On the server side you parse the body, chuck in a DB and you're set. You could then have a webservice http://myserver.com/topScores.php which returns json, xml, whatever of top scores. Or just return the same from postScore.php if you want it immediately.

Remember to block against SQL injection if you're using MySQL.

Comment: So basically, you are saying I can make a webservice in html or javascript etc. that maybe contains a submit high score feature. When users of the windows phone game want to submit a high score it parses the webservice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a WCF Restfull Service in .NET which can help you and it will give you a data in XML as well as JSON format,

you can refer the link [WCF REST](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)